# stop iCloud back up

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, icloud, icloud-drive

I am new in iOS development. My app was rejected because it must follow the iOS Data Storage Guidelines. I have already read some answer here on Stack Overflow, and I have already read some blogs.

I am using this following method in my appdelegate.m for stop icloud back up. My database size is 79mb.

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtPath:(NSString *)path {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path];
    assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path]]);
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL success = [url setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES] forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];
    if(!success){
        NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@",[url lastPathComponent],error);
    }
    return success;
}
```

I have also used this code:

```
 NSArray *pathsa = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([pathsa count] > 0) ? [pathsa objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    NSArray *documents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:basePath error:nil];
    NSURL *URL;
    NSString *completeFilePath;
    for (NSString *file in documents) {
        completeFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", basePath, file];
        URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:completeFilePath];
        NSLog(@"File %@  is excluded from backup %@", file, [URL resourceValuesForKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey] error:nil]);
    }
```

But still its showing 109 MB in iCloud Storage.

Comment: How do you open your Sqlite database if you don't know the path to the file?

Comment: i am using following code for open database.                                                                 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:ddb];

Comment: Could that last `*path` be your database path then?

Comment: I am using Dbmanager class for create databse.i want call my database path in appdelegate class.